# How to create this circular smoke effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I need an effect like this, I have smoke brushes but I need something in a cricle shape, so that I can wrap it around a human body. Can it be done using Photoshop or Illustrator?

[image: Here]

Comment: You can't paint circles with your "smoke brushes"?

Comment: @Scott I tried but that doesn't give smooth and connected path. Anyone can notice multiple brush strokes joined together. Plus, the beginning and end should be thin.

Comment: So you can use a graphics tablet. The stylus with these devices is pressure sensitive, allowing different thicknesses/and or opacity depending on how hard you press.

Comment: Or.. as shown below.. simply paint a straight horizontal line and use the Polar Coordinates filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a good smoke brush, paint an approximately horizontal stroke on a transparent background. Place it in the middle of the image. Generate some twists with the smudge tool. Let the left and right ends be narrow. Use eraser and fix with smudge tool.

Apply Filter > Distort > Polar coordinates to get a ring. Apply perspective distortion if needed.

If you use ordinary brushes, you can as well draw a circle and stroke it instead of using Polar Coordinates. You must create the richness by painting, smudging and erasing. You can smooth the traces of manual brushing with Radial spin blur and by doing very careful smudging. Insert possible perspective when the ring is otherwise ready.

Here's one result. No smoke brush is used, only an ordinary one. Radial spin blur before the perspective insertion helped to fade the remnants of manual brush strokes. It got plenty of smudging to make the richness

[image]

Comment: There's a warp tool in Illustrator (Shift + R). Is there such warp tool in Photoshop? There's smudge tool but it's different.

Comment: I know liquify filter, Puppet warp and Different Transform tools. But was just asking. Isn't there any straight forward tool?

Comment: Liquify filter is the closest equivalent in Photoshop. Unfortunately it works in a separate dialog and if you need a reference image for the work, you must activate option "Show Backdrop". That can be one of the existing layers.

Answer (score 6):

This can actually be done fairly easily with Photoshop. However, detailing the steps necessary takes more effort than actually creating the artwork (smoke). It took 10 times longer to write this post than it does to simply create the image.

---

---

## There is nothing "solid" here.

Every time you do these steps you'll get a *different* image. You will **not** get the same image I got. And I couldn't create that same image twice. The entire point of this method is its *randomness*.

---

---

These are the *basic steps* to show how you could achieve something similar without any special brush work or painting skills. It's all filter choices and slider adjustments.

These steps are to explore the *method* and not to provide a final usable image from this post.

[image]

---

---

## Procedure

- New Document
- Black base layer
- Second transparent layer to paint on
- Paint a straight, white, horizontal, stroke.... nothing special, just a straight line within the canvas area (stay away from the image edges)

[image]

- Choose `Filter > Distort > Polar Coordinates`. Make certain **Rectangular to Polar** is selected and click `OK`.

[image]
[image]

- Use `Edit > Free Transform` to distort the ring into perspective (Holding down Modifier keys while dragging handles will allow for perspective distortion).

[image]

- Add a **Layer Mask** to the paint layer
- With this Layer Mask highlighted, choose `Filter > Render Clouds` from the menu
- Still with the mask highlighted, choose `Image > Adjustments > Levels` to increase contrast of the mask.

[image]

You may need to *unlink* the mask with the layer and then move the **mask** around a bit to position the "poofs" a little better. When you are happy with positioning Control-Click/Right-click the Mask and choose `Apply Layer Mask` from the contextual menu.

[image]

- Choose `Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur` from the menu and blur the ring... No special settings, simply blur it quite a bit.

[image]

- Choose `Filter > Other > Maximum` from the menu. Make certain the filer drop down menu is set to **Preserve Roundeness** and move the slider right to get a more random density shape.

[image]

- Choose `Filter > Distort > Wave` from the menu. The settings you use here are your choice. The only important aspect is that you have it set to **Sine** for the `Type` in the upper right corner.

[image]

[image]

- Choose `Edit > Fade Wave` from the menu. Set the blend drop down to **Screen** and lower the opacity until the distorted image fades in well.

[image]

- You can repeat the last couple steps... Filter > Wave and adjust settings slightly (or click the "randomize" button) and then Fade the wave, choosing various opacities. The more you do this more the more "random" the smoke may become. It takes some experimentation.

[image]

---

Repeat **any** of the above steps to keep refining.

- Add another **Layer Mask** to the paint layer and choose `Filter > Render > Clouds` again.. and adjust levels as needed.

[image]

- Run the `Maximum` Filter again

### [image]

Comment: +1 ...& for your next trick - https://imgur.com/r/MovieDetails/b02hhNY  ;)

Comment: You SHALL NOT PASS!!!!!! `:)` Gandolf has me beat.. every stinkin' time. Darn it! `:)`

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer more than once!